# Sending file with Flask test client raises "FileStorage is not JSON serializable"

Tags: python, flask

I am testing sending some files to a Flask route. However, I get the error `TypeError: <FileStorage: 'test_photo.jpg' ('image/jpeg')> is not JSON serializable`. Looking through the route, `'/new-ad/write-details`, there is nothing that is attempting to JSON serialize this field.

```
video_file = open(test_helpers.get_dummy_file('test_video.mp4'), 'rb')
image_file = open(test_helpers.get_dummy_file('test_photo.jpg'), 'rb')
response = self.app.post(
    '/new-ad/write-details',
    buffered=True,
    content_type='multipart/form-data',
    data={
        'location_id': db.session.query(Location).first().id,
        'category_id': db.session.query(Category).first().id,
        'title': 'test title',
        'body': 'test body',
        'add_video': (video_file, 'test_video.mp4'),
        'add_images': (image_file, 'test_photo.jpg')})
assert response.status_code == 302
assert response.location.partition('?')[0] == 'http://localhost/new-ad/preview'
ad_id = response.location.partition('?')[2].partition('=')[2]
video_file.close()
image_file.close()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 144, in test_ads_creation_routes
    'add_images': (image_file, 'test_photo.jpg')})
  File "/home/dev/Projects/ggp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 801, in post
    return self.open(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/dev/Projects/ggp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/testing.py", line 127, in open
    follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
  File "/home/dev/Projects/ggp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 764, in open
    response = self.run_wsgi_app(environ, buffered=buffered)
  File "/home/dev/Projects/ggp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 677, in run_wsgi_app
    rv = run_wsgi_app(self.application, environ, buffered=buffered)
  File "/home/dev/Projects/ggp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 884, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/dev/Projects/ggp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/dev/Projects/ggp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/dev/Projects/ggp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/dev/Projects/ggp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/dev/Projects/ggp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/dev/Projects/ggp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/home/dev/Projects/ggp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1632, in finalize_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
  File "/home/dev/Projects/ggp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1858, in process_response
    self.save_session(ctx.session, response)
  File "/home/dev/Projects/ggp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 924, in save_session
    return self.session_interface.save_session(self, session, response)
  File "/home/dev/Projects/ggp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 363, in save_session
    val = self.get_signing_serializer(app).dumps(dict(session))
  File "/home/dev/Projects/ggp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 565, in dumps
    payload = want_bytes(self.dump_payload(obj))
  File "/home/dev/Projects/ggp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 847, in dump_payload
    json = super(URLSafeSerializerMixin, self).dump_payload(obj)
  File "/home/dev/Projects/ggp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 550, in dump_payload
    return want_bytes(self.serializer.dumps(obj))
  File "/home/dev/Projects/ggp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 85, in dumps
    return json.dumps(_tag(value), separators=(',', ':'))
  File "/home/dev/Projects/ggp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/json.py", line 123, in dumps
    rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 237, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 198, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 256, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/home/dev/Projects/ggp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/json.py", line 80, in default
    return _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <FileStorage: 'test_photo.jpg' ('image/jpeg')> is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: If you want to send binary data via HTTP, then send the data as `multipart/form-data` as OP even is attempting to do. That’s what it’s made for, to transfer files. Do not even attempt to serialize binary data *as a string* inside JSON. Apart from the already huge security implications of pickling objects from a remote source, this is super inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've shown works, and is not related to the error you've shown. The error indicates that you're trying to add a file object to the `session`. This is a bad idea.

The session is a cookie, which is not only limited in size but is sent to the server with every request the client makes. Adding a whole file to it greatly increases network traffic for no reason.

If you really need a file in the session, or in any JSON response, add a reference to its path on disk, not the data itself. Then when you need the file make a request to serve the file separately. Web servers are very good at serving files.

```
return jsonify({'video': '/path/to/video.mp4'})
```

If, for some reason, you *really* need to add file data to a JSON payload (but really, you don't), serialize it using base64 first. This is inefficient in space and time, so consider it as a last resort only.

```
from base64 import b64encode
return jsonify({'video': b64encode(video.read())})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to reproduce without your test code.

```
f = open('{path_to_file}', 'rb')
print(type(f))

import json
json.dumps(f)
```

`json.dumps` will throw exception since a file object is not inherently JSON serializable.

Flask is trying to serialize the contents before sending it, and failing. If you want to send the file contents to your server, you want to read in the contents and send the bytes.

```
with open('{path_to_file}', 'rb') as f:
    contents = f.read()
```